# PostgreSQL: Is there a way to have an integer column always output in hexadecimal?

Tags: postgresql, hex

I'd like to store integers in a table in such a way that selection from that table always output those integers in hexadecimal, without having to call `to_hex`. I tried creating a domain with a cast, only to learn that casts of domains are noops.  I suppose this could be done with a view, but do I have any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no facility to do that.  A view sounds like a good solution.